# Adding skins/themes to an iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios4

We've complete an app in iPhone. For the next version, we want to add skins/themes to the app. There are some good replies to similar posts that I read on stack overflow regarding this and different developers have given varying ways to solve the same. But anyone who's actually been able to accomplish this and get an acceptance from the app store, could he/she/they please post a solution to this?

Comment: i got a solution for adding skins. now i need to find how i can save the skin once it is applied.

Comment: can you describe your solution of adding skins?

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to look into [singletons](http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/?p=290). I don't know all that much about them, but they are basically information that any part of the app can access.

You would need to save the user's theme preference as a singleton, then in your scenes would need to get the information about the user's preference off that singleton, and run a method that would check what the preference was load up different background/images/sprites depending on that.

Comment: the link you have provided is about cocos2d which is usually used for games only